# Why CSS sibling (~) selector doesn't work with :checked?

Tags: html, css, css-selectors, siblings

I can't get :checked to work with ~

```css
#menu {
  background-color: red;
}

#trigger:checked ~ #menu {
  background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<input type="checkbox" id="trigger" />
<div id="menu">
  <h1>Hello</h1>
</div>
```

Here's a CodePen of the issue: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/jowQWJ

Can someone explain why it doesn't work?

I must be missing something very obvious 'cause it seems pretty straightforward to me...

Comment: issue with codepen probably, it's working fine here

Comment: even without `:checked` it's not working on codepen

Comment: it seems a bad copy/past from somewhere. There is some strange character between `~`, remove them then add space again

Comment: I can't believe it was a strange character, I must have been copy pasting it every time... Thank you very much it's working now!